tikz/external: Error writing files
The following code used to work before but now it is having trouble to write output files to destination, what is the problem here?

Tried solution from this issue but it didn't work

command:
lualatex
--synctex=0
--shell-escape
--output-dir=.build
--interaction=nonstopmode
--file-line-error
main.tex

File tree:

main.log:
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 
'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "./.build/figures/figure.0.0.0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"'
did NOT result in a usable output file 
'./.build/figures/figure.0.0.0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). 
Please verify that you have enabled system calls. 
For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. 
Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. 
Or maybe the command simply failed? 
Error messages can be found in './.build/figures/figure.0.0.0.log'. 
If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

main.tex (MWE):
\documentclass{standalone}

% ========================= Tikz ========================= %
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{babel}
% ===================== External lib ===================== %
% \usepackage{shellesc} % Solution from similar question (doesnt work)
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzsetfigurename{figure.\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.} % set figure names
\tikzset{external/system call={%
    lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
    -halt-on-error
    -interaction=batchmode
    -jobname "\image" "\texsource"
    % --jobname "\image" \subfilename
}}

\tikzexternalize[
    up to date check={simple}, % faster check
    figure list={true}, % generate list of figures file
    prefix={./.build/figures/}
] % turn externalization on/off
% Fix background
\NewCommandCopy\oldtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\RenewDocumentCommand\tikzpicture{O{}}{\oldtikzpicture[#1]\nopagecolor}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{external/remake next=true}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \draw[->, thick, blue!60!]
    ( 0,  0)--node[anchor=south west]{\( A \)}
    (-1,0.5);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Turns out \tikzsetexternalprefix{...} starts as root file already inside .build directory, so setting \tikzsetexternalprefix{./figures/} solved the issue.
